# Page not found (404) The current path, register/register, didn’t match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, web-deployment

[on running server browser show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeeEX.png)

I am trying to save the the data into database on submitting the form the browser show page not found error and and some wrong address.  http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/register while i am rendering the homepage on submitting the form.

views.py file

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def homePage(request):
    return render(request,"index.html")

def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
         firstname = request.POST.get('fname')
         lastname = request.POST.get('lname')
         email = request.POST.get('email')
         password = request.POST.get('password')
         username = request.POST.get('uname')
         user = User(first_name=firstname,last_name=lastname,email=email,password=password,username=username)
         user.save()
    return redirect('/')

    return render(request,"register.html")

def course(request):
    return HttpResponse("welcome to my 2nd page")

def courseDetail(request,courseid):
    return HttpResponse(courseid)
```

urls.py file

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from name import views
import name
urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('',views.homePage),
 path('register/',views.register),
 path('course/',views.course),
 path('course/<courseid>',views.courseDetail),
]
```

Comment: please share your project's `urls.py` file. 
Moreover, I have noticed `return redirect('/')` this line out of the "if" scope.

Comment: it is given below the view.py file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try
path('register/register',views.register),

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's problem with your form. You have `register/` URL with slash on the end. So, your form relative `register/` action and send request to the `register/register` URL.

Try to remove trailing slash in `url.py`

`path('register',views.register),`